# SwiftUI elements inside HStack have different heights

Tags: ios, swift, button, text, swiftui

I have a Button and a Text inside the HStack:

```
HStack{
      Button(action: {}) {
             Text(" Text ")
             .padding()
             .background(Color.blue)
             .foregroundColor(.white)
             .font(.headline)
             .cornerRadius(5)
              }

              Text("")
              .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
              .padding()
              .background(Color.gray)
              .font(.headline)
              .cornerRadius(5)
}
```

Both Texts have the same font, padding and etc., but the button is always higher than the second text. How to make them equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. The second text shouldn't be the empty string like "", it should at least contain spaces, like "   ".